# Formatting dynamically generated checkboxes?

Tags: php

I've got a system that gathers information out of XML files, for the exporter I have been trying to create a system where it gathers the unique imprints from a SQL table then outputs them & uses it for the export query so we can export only what we are after at that time & not everything.

The code I have does  the above fine however I've been trying to format it to sit within a table and every 7/8 iterations it starts a new table row however I've been unsuccessful at this point, with 167 rows currently I want it to look a bit better than a massive list (and easier to use).

The code I have currently is the following:

```
    <table>
<form action="exporttrade.php" method="post">
<b>Please Select imprints you wish to Export for <client></b><br />

<?PHP
mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db("database");

    $sql ="SELECT distinct imprint FROM table";
    $results= mysql_query($sql);
    while( $imprint = mysql_fetch_assoc($results) ):
?>

    <tr><td><?php echo $imprint['imprint']; ?></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="imprint[]" value="<?php echo $imprint['imprint']; ?>"/></td></tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I've been attempting to use a counter and modulo function I've seen online to insert code every nth line (in this case will be the ending < /tr> tag. Does anyone here know how you can sucessfully do what I am after?  I'm just a bit stumped at how  to format this currently :/

Edit - Just a heads up managed to get this working as I wanted it to now used the following:

```
$imprints=grab_array($sql);
foreach ($imprints as $imprint){
$imprint=$imprint['imprint'];
$counter++;
if($counter % 8 == 0){
    echo "</tr><tr>";
}
?>
<td><?php echo $imprint; ?></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="imprint[]" value="<?php echo $imprint; ?>"/></td>
<?PHP
   }    
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to format your table? and make your table look better so that its understood properly?

Comment: Pretty much currently I can only get it to either spread everything horizontally or vertically. I want to be able to say every 8 instances of the while loop to add a < /tr> so it the table will have 8 columns x 20 odd rows.

Rather than the current 167x1 / 1x167 but it just doesn't want to play ball currently when I've  tried using counters etc to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<table>
<form action="exporttrade.php" method="post">
<b>Please Select imprints you wish to Export for <client></b><br />

<?PHP
mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db("database");
$count = 0;
    $sql ="SELECT distinct imprint FROM table";
    $results= mysql_query($sql);
    while( $imprint = mysql_fetch_assoc($results) ):
    if($imprint)
{
 count++;
}
while($count <= 8)
?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $imprint['imprint']; ?></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="imprint[]" value="<?php echo $imprint['imprint']; ?>"/></td></tr> 

<?php 
$count = 0;  echo '<tr><td> New Row after 8 </td> </tr>'?>
<?php continue ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

you can use this logic.

Comment: Thanks this is currently running, but its been ~5 or so mins (at least) and currently nothing so seems  something may be up but not quite sure what

Comment: <?php

$count = 0;

for ($count =0;$count<=100;$count++)
 {
echo "do something";
   while($count == 8)

        echo $count;
}
?>
try this logic. and instead of calling and another php file. try calling it in same file. i.e put < form action=#>

Comment: Trying that now thanks, The calling to another file is for where the form will submit too (I just haven't put the submit button on yet or built  that up, been wanting the check boxes to work before I started on that front really.

Comment: As I can't seem to edit, sorry for the double post but this also appears to be stuck doing nothing, it prints out the <b>Please select imprints..</b> then just nothing :/ Don't really fancy or want to hardcode in all options as if a new imprint is received in the file it won't be known about for some time after.. This is turning into more of a pain to get working than I imagined.

Comment: can you post an image?

Comment: Of which part sorry?

I may have put  the latest bit of code you provided in the wrong place, I put it just above the creation of the check boxes so like :

    while($imprint = mysql_fetch_assoc($results) ):
  $count = 0; for ($count =0;$count<=100;$count++) { echo "</tr><tr>"; while($count == 8) echo $count; } ?>

    <td><?php echo $imprint['imprint']; ?></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="imprint[]" value="<?php echo $imprint['imprint']; ?>"/></td>
<?php endwhile; ?>

As said this may be wrong, if so my bad, chrome just crashed out for  this with 'an error' didn't actually say what.